# Troubleshoting query_post(), how to get the current or last SQL query performed by function call

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my theme:

```
<?php 
    global $query_string;
    query_posts($query_string . "posts_per_page=".get_option('onthego_fromblog_random')."&ignore_sticky_posts=1&orderby=rand&cat=".get_catid(get_option('onthego_blog_cat'))); 
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('includes/fromblog_post'); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But it's not getting results and I need to know which is the SQL query generated by `query_post()` in order to test it in phpMyAdmin or other tool. How? I look trough documentation but doesn't find any helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't You just put in this code in a while

```
die(creating query code...);
```

and go to the page that using it?
So in Your case it will be

```
die($query_string . "posts_per_page=".get_option('onthego_fromblog_random')."&ignore_sticky_posts=1&orderby=rand&cat=".get_catid(get_option('onthego_blog_cat')));
```

And You can copy this query & paste it to PMA.

Comment: This give me something like that `posts_per_page=3&ignore_sticky_posts=1&orderby=rand&cat=1 ` but not the entire SQL query

Answer (score 1):

There's a codex page entitled [Debugging in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), which talks about using `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` to create an array of executed queries.

Alternatively, you can set MySQL to log queries by adding `log = log_file_name` to your `my.cnf` file.

Comment: Ok, I've added those two lines to my `wp-config.php`: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` but ... where I should see the debug information and savequeries information? In DB?

Comment: Nevermind I found a plugin for that, now I only see this query: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 0, 3` is that right one based on the parameters I set? I'm newbie in WP world

Comment: What do You want to achieve? Is this query returns any results?